# How to get any value of array with knowing one another value of that array in php

Tags: php, arrays

My array is

```
      Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [new_id] => 945
                    [affiliate_id] => 190
                    [scalelab_percent] => 0.1
                    [affiliate_percent] => 0.2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [new_id] => 946
                    [affiliate_id] => 33
                    [scalelab_percent] => 0.2
                    [affiliate_percent] => 0.1
                )



            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [new_id] => 952
                    [affiliate_id] => 33
                    [scalelab_percent] => 0.25
                    [affiliate_percent] => 0.1
                )



        )
```

I want to get `affiliate_percent` where I know `affiliate_id` is 33 and I want its single result 0.1 means, there should not be multiple result **0.1**

Comment: [foreach](http://www.php.net//manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: We need an [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) reference question.

Comment: yes.. i know it will be through foreach. But i can not solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if ($arr['affiliate_id'] == 33) {
        $percent = $arr['affiliate_percent'];
        break;
    }
}
```

This is just a simple example of the logic you need to find the percent. `33` could be replaced with a variable, and additional checks could be done after the loop to confirm that `$percent` was actually found.